# What is past the world border of the nether in Minecraft Console Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

What happens if you glitch or hack the game to remove the bedrock at the world border in the Nether in Minecraft Console Edition?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you just run around in a blue screen there are a few YouTube Videos out there showing this  here is one for example.

Comment: Video in answer is dead.

Answer (score -1):

If you dig up to the world border on top of the nether and break the bedrock is like super flat world in the nether.

Answer (score -2):

You will get into a "side-void"
Let me explain:
In MCJE and MCBE, there are two voids in the nether, one at the tip top, one on the bottom. While on MCLCE, both voids are connected by a third one on the edge.